# Percentage Query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables as shown below :

Tabel_1

```
|idUnit  |  Budget |
|112     |  1000   |
|112     |  2000   |
|113     |  4000   |
```

Tabel_2

```
|idUnit  | Real2   |
|112     | 500     |
|112     | 100     |
|113     | 200     |
```

My Question, how to make the table as below with percentage:

```
| idUnit  | TotalBudget | TotalReal2 | Percentage 
| 112     | 3000        | 600        | ? (15%)    |
| 113     | 4000        | 200        | ? (5%)     |
```

My query before :

```
SELECT t1.idUnit, SUM(Budget) AS TotalBudget, t2.TotalReal2
FROM Tabel_1 AS t1
  JOIN (SELECT idUnit, SUM(Real2) AS TotalReal2
        FROM Tabel_2 GROUP BY idUnit
  ) AS t2 ON t1.idUnit = t2.idUnit
GROUP BY t1.idUnit;
```

Comment: What's your percentage logic?

Comment: I can't understand why `idUnit = 112 ` is equal 15%

Comment: (totalreal/totalbudget)*100

Comment: But `600/3000` should be 20%?

Comment: ups sorry D-Shih you're right 20%

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use two subqueries then do JOIN, calculating your column by `TotalBudget` and `totalbudget`

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t1.idUnit, 
       t1.TotalBudget, 
       t2.TotalReal2,
       CONCAT((TotalReal2/totalbudget)*100,'%') Percentage 
FROM (
    SELECT idUnit,SUM(Budget) TotalBudget 
    FROM Tabel_1
    GROUP BY idUnit
) AS t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT idUnit, 
           SUM(Real2) AS TotalReal2
    FROM Tabel_2 
    GROUP BY idUnit
) AS t2 ON t1.idUnit = t2.idUnit
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b8b17/3/0)**:

```
| idUnit | TotalBudget | TotalReal2 | Percentage |
|--------|-------------|------------|------------|
|    112 |        3000 |        600 |   20.0000% |
|    113 |        4000 |        200 |    5.0000% |
```

Comment: TotalBudget incorret, and how to percentage into two decimal digits

Comment: Add `ROUND` and define decimal places like `CONCAT(ROUND((TotalReal2/totalbudget)*100,2),'%')` @CaswitoSlow

Comment: Work for percentage but still incorrect for result value TotalBudget

Comment: How come it's incorrect? I see this suggested solution returned the same `TotalBudget` value for each `idUnit` as what you post in the question. If the values here are incorrect, what could be the correct value then?